# Is there a relation between covariance matrices and real and imaginary part of eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Apology if my question not clear or appropriate. Consider a complex positive definite sample covariance matrix (SCM) A, generated by a band limited signal on a set of sensors which is termed as data matrix, D. Now, we modified the data matrix D by multiplying each column i.e. each sensor signal by a complex number. We are multiplying each column by a complex number so that we are rotating all the column vector towards a particular direction. From this new data matrix we would get another SCM, B.

Now the question: Is there a relation between the direction we are multiplying each column of A and the eigenvectors of B? Is there a relation between the real and imaginary part of the Eigenvectors of the SCM?